# Custom ListView layout crashes my activity

Tags: android

I am starting out on Android and trying to make a custom ListView layout. I've followed some guides and have made the following code:

```
public class CheckInList extends ListActivity {
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.checkinlist_item, R.id.checkinlist_item_text, mNames);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the code for checkinlist_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/checkinlist_item_bg">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/checkinlist_item_text"
              style="@style/RegisterText" />
</RelativeView>
```

If I use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of my above template then everything is fine and my ListView works, however whenever I use the above code my activity crashes. I am running things on Android 1.5.

Any ideas why things are crashing?

Comment: Could you add the error you get via LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be because `RelativeView` does not exist?

Comment: Thanks, this was certainly one of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest adding the attributes `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` or set them to whatever you want, but those are required. And yes, use `RelativeLayout` as Matthew said, since `RelativeView` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

at first sight there is no width/height values for your textView ?

Comment: They can be defined in the style.

Comment: no offense but "I am starting out on Android" - i totally agree with you on this

Comment: hmm, with the description about how the app is crashing it does seem likely to be a lack of layout_{width,height}

Comment: Thanks, this was the second issue. Matthew's comment was the first issue.